# How to make Multi lingual application in asp.net mvc 3 using Razor view engine with resource file

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am beginner in mvc and I need an introduction 
How to make Multi Language Application in asp.net mvc 3 using Razor view engine with resource file

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you reading the official tutorials: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/internationalization